# Magento 2 - How to create the batch file to export product to csv file

Tags: magento2, cron, console

In Magento 2, How to create the batch file to export product to csv file? 
May you show me step by step, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Manual export:
go BO->System->Export select Entity Type (Products)

Automatic export (general solution):
1. Create module with model extends from Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product set parameters and run method export()
2. Set cron on run your custom export

Comment: I need more detail, please!